# Identify and Decode Opus stream to PCM

Tags: javascript, audio, pcm, opus, raw

The company I'm working with has an overseas microphone manufacturer. It's been quite difficult to communicate with them. So far I know the data being streamed back has "8:1 Opus Compression" and the chip they're using is [ats2837](https://www.i-lexia.com/productinfo/266148.html)... I created a sample recording, and stored all the data that're being streamed back. The total byte is 14760, which then I would decode it into PCM that represent 3 seconds of audio. So far I identified repeating header which is "5b 50", and I turned it into chunks. Can someone give me a clue what I'm dealing with here? [section of the stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMOhj.png)

Here's the [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11Ftt5nhWtQanM2Jq6Q-aeIjOOrL6u4AC?usp=drive_link) to stream output to a encoded text file and just plain hex I got from the device.

I'm writing the logic in Javascript, and I used "audify" library. But when imported it into Audacity, I just get bunch of white noise. Here's the link to the [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/audify).

```js
const { OpusEncoder, OpusDecoder, OpusApplication } = require('audify');

// 8000, 12000, 16000, 24000, or 48000
const newDecoder = new OpusDecoder(48000, 1);
const frameSize = 1920; // 40ms
var decodedArr = [];

pcmDataChucks.forEach(d => {
  let decimal = hexStringToDecimalArray(d);
  let decoded = newDecoder.decode(Buffer.from(decimal.slice(2, decimal.length)), frameSize);
  decoded = new Uint8Array(decoded);
  decodedArr = [...decodedArr, ...decoded];
})

fs.writeFile('audio_test.txt', Buffer.from(decodedArr), (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error writing to file:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('File has been written successfully.');
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you post a copy of the file?

Comment: Please don't post code as image, [edit] your question and post as text instead.

Comment: I've added the link to the file.

Comment: We also need to see your input(i.e. source) file. Since you say it's Opus coded, it should open in Audacity, right? Also your code is incomplete, and you give no link to 'audify' library. Why are you writing to a text file if you want PCM?

Comment: I added the input source into Google Drive - the plain hex I got back from the device when I request audio. Also to be clear, my struggle is that manufacturer say it's Opus encoded, but I think the stream also have custom headers, etc. Because from all the converter platform, it says it's not valid Opus format. I tried to wrap it in ogg container, but it's hard without knowing how it was encoded from the start on the firmware side